# selecting time only from datetime

Tags: mysql

Can someone please explain to me why the first code doesn't work? in the first one I am try to extract time only and input in the Time column.

```
UPDATE SampleData_0816
SELECT Time1 = DATE_FORMAT(opened_first_time, '%h:%i')


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(opened_first_time, '%h:%i')
FROM SampleData_0816
```

Comment: get a data from DB, and using `explode or split` http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php      and http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the update function you must use SET instead of SELECT

```
UPDATE SampleData_0816
SET Time1 = DATE_FORMAT(opened_first_time'%H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: I did initially but still doesn't work. I don't understand why!

Comment: it works but the date in the opened_first_time  column is like this 2015-03-30 10:47:39 and I want the data in Time column to be like 10:47:39

Comment: That is because the Time1 is a DATETIME type meaning that it needs to be a date with a time format example: 2016-01-01 12:00:00 change it to TIME, and use the edited code above

Comment: hi, it's still not working even after changing the Type as "TIME". still getting the same error

Comment: are you sure opened_first_time is a date?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName, '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY, 
   DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY
```

You can achieve that using DATE_FORMAT().